# Twitter4j Screen name of User who has retweet a specific tweet

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have an  ArrayList with Status of a specific  user. 
How can get the screen name of users have retweet the Statuses?

Thank you

Comment: Read their Javadocs: http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc.html

Comment: I try It... I found a solution using query (RT @username or VIA @username) but I want to do it using Class Status. Any idea?

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Answer (score 0):

Check **getRetweeterIds** method in http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TweetsResources.html